# Select only unique row/record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to see how I can get only unique row/records that have a unique city and not care if it's capital so for example:

```
Akron
akron
aKRON
```

would only return one record.

I tired something like this but it doesn't work

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(city) AS city,state_prefix,lattitude,longitude  FROM zip_code WHERE city LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10"
```

Thank you...

Comment: Can you tell us what type of collation you have on `city` field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this mysql-only trick:

```
SELECT city, state_prefix, lattitude,longitude
FROM zip_code WHERE city LIKE '$queryString%'
GROUP BY city, state_prefix -- Here's the trick
LIMIT 10
```

This will return the *first row encountered* for each unique value of `city` and `state_prefix`.

Other databases will complain that you have non=-aggregated columns not listed in the group by or some such message.

#### Edited

Previously I claimed that not using the `upper()` function on the grouped-by columns it would return all case variations, but that was incorrect - thanks to SalmanA for pointing that out. I verified using SQLFiddle and you don't need to use `upper()`.

Comment: Normally MySQL will not care whether a column value is upper or lower case (depends on collation of course).

Comment: You need to put the rest of the select parameters in the group by or if you have a similar named city in another state, it will group them together.  Springfield, MA and Springfield, CT...

Comment: @SalmanA I didn't realise that (you are quire correct - I verified using SQLFiddle). Thanks for that.

Comment: @Bohemian i don't think it's correct to say that it will return the fist row encountered... it will return an undetermined row... the fact that it's always the first is just coincidence :)

Comment: @fthiella: first row in the order in which mysql gets the rows. It is the _order_ which is undetermined :)

Comment: @SalmanA yep, first row encountered by mysql :) that's correct!

Comment: @fthiella I know the documentation *says* it could be *any* row, even if selected from an inner ordered query, but the practicality is that it's the first row encountered. In the many times I have used this trick, I have never seen mysql do anything else. It's in practice quite deterministic when you *first* order, *then* group by (despite the doco). When grouping over an unordered set, the practicality is that it returns the first row it reads from disk (undeterministic), but in queries like this is doesn't matter

Comment: @Bohemian yes, in queries like this it doesn't matter, and it is right that it always return the first row when you order first, i have tried in every possible way and i wasn't able to make this trick fail! but since the docs says it could be any row, i am always a bit worried to relay on something that's not documented.. but since it's also widely used, i think it will always work!

Comment: Note that (i) `ORDER BY` is applied _after_ grouping, not _before_ (ii) if a `GROUP BY` query does not have an `ORDER BY` the results are still ordered (iii) The row returned by a partial `GROUP BY` is the first one encountered for each group in the order MySQL reads data, which could be affected by the way data is stored in files, indexes used, rows are deleted then inserted, etc. It is not deterministic.

Comment: This is a horrible answer as it goes against the sql standard! By now even mysql realised this and changed the default settings of sql mode to block such queries.

Comment: @Shadow and yet, it works (if the appropriate MySQL settings are in place). If unit and system tests pass, the code is good to ship.

Comment: Your answer does not say anything about settings (this was configurable back in 2012, too, just the default value was changed later). The behaviour you rely on can change without warning and have seen cases where after a lot of delete and insert the behaviour was not as you described. So, the code may work under certain circumstances only.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work on other DBMS, but in MySql you could use this:

```
SELECT city, state_prefix,lattitude,longitude
FROM zip_code WHERE city LIKE '$queryString%'
GROUP BY city
LIMIT 10
```

MySql ignores case when comparing strings, e.g. this returns true:

```
select 'hello'='Hello '
```

and you can also group by a single field (city in this case) and return all others field. Values of other fields are undetermined, they are usually the ones in the first row but you can't relay on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can us a function in a GROUP BY to convert all names to upper or lowercase:

```
 SELECT  city,state_prefix,lattitude,longitude 
        FROM zip_code WHERE city LIKE '$queryString%'
        GROUP BY UPPER(city), UPPER(state_prefix) LIMIT 10
```

I'm assuming if a city and state match, lattitude and longitude can be safely rolled up.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your table, or your city column, has a case-sensitive collation setting.

You can choose the collation explicitly in your SELECT statement like so.  If you choose a case-insensitive collation, the `DISTINCT` keyword will do what you want it to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        city COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
        state_prefix COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
        lattitude,longitude  
 FROM zip_code 
WHERE city LIKE '$queryString%' 
LIMIT 10
```